# How to edit a file using a specified editor?

Tags: delphi

Currently, I'm using the following function in order to open a file using the default editor and be sure my application waits until the user closes the editor window.

```
function EditAndWait(const AFileName : string) : boolean;
var
  Info: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  FillChar(Info, SizeOf(Info), 0);
  Info.cbSize := SizeOf(Info);
  Info.lpVerb := 'edit';
  Info.lpFile := PAnsiChar(AFileName);
  Info.nShow := SW_SHOW;
  Info.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  Result := ShellExecuteEx(@Info);
  if(Result) and (Info.hProcess <> 0) then 
  begin
    WaitForSingleObject(Info.hProcess, Infinite);
    CloseHandle(Info.hProcess);
  end;
end;
```

I would like write a similar function which allow to specify the editor executable to use for editing.

```
function EditAndWait(const AFileName : string; const AEditor : string) : boolean;
begin
  //...
end;
```

Comment: Create a process with that editor passing the file as an argument. Wait for it to close. Both parts have many examples that can be found by searching.

Comment: Take a look at [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: Your code has a resource leak. Remember to close the process handle afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David said, it can be done by running the editor program and passing the file as a parameter.

There are several ways to do it. This is the most similar to the current function:

```
function EditAndWait(const AFileName : string; const AEditor : string) : boolean;
var
  Info: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  FillChar(Info, SizeOf(Info), 0);
  Info.cbSize := SizeOf(Info);
  Info.lpVerb := 'open';
  Info.lpFile := PChar(AEditor);
  Info.nShow := SW_SHOW;
  Info.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  Info.lpParameters := PChar(AFileName);
  Result := ShellExecuteEx(@Info);
  if(Result) and (Info.hProcess <> 0) then 
  begin
    CloseHandle(Info.hProcess);
    WaitForSingleObject(Info.hProcess, Infinite);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: To add, I would default `AEditor` to an empty string, and when this function is called without, then it will call the default one. That way, no need for two separate functions.

Comment: Neglecting error checking is a mistake. I'd also use CreateProcess and avoid going round the houses getting SEE to call CP for you.